# How to build custom layer with vulkan layer factory on ubuntu?

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to make a custom layer on ubuntu using the vulkan layer factory. I can successfully build it on the `sdk-1.1.101` branch by doing this:

```
cd VulkanTools
mkdir build
cd build
../scripts/update_deps.py
cmake -C helper.cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

However I'm not sure how to actually install / run the layer.
One solution I have found is to set `VK_LAYER_PATH=/home/user/VulkanTools/build/layers/staging-json/` and edit the .json for my layer so that it points to the `.so` file in `/home/user/VulkanTools/build/layers/`.

However I get this error

```
vk_image: /home/user/VulkanTools/build/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/build/install/include/vk_layer_logging.h:959: bool log_msg(const debug_report_data*, VkFlags, VkDebugReportObjectTypeEXT, uint64_t, std::__cxx11::string, const char*, ...): Assertion `0' failed.
```

If I run the `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_starter_layer` it works however if I change the `.json` file for starter_layer to point to the `.so` file in `/home/user/VulkanTools/build/layers/` I get the same error as above.

I have the lunarg sdk installed via apt-get and have tried to build the layer by specifying:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=build/install -DVULKAN_HEADERS_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/ -DVULKAN_LOADER_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/ -DVULKAN_VALIDATIONLAYERS_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/ ..
```

But this results in:

```
[  3%] Building CXX object layer_factory/CMakeFiles/VkLayer_assistant_layer.dir/layer_factory.cpp.o
/home/user/VulkanTools/build/layer_factory/layer_factory.cpp:31:10: fatal error: vk_loader_platform.h: No such file or directory
 #include "vk_loader_platform.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Does anyone have any advice as to the process of building layers using the layer factory on ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Can you show me the debug output from the loader?
i.e. ```
VK_LOADER_DEBUG=all VK_LAYER_PATH=</dir/containing/json> VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=<your_layer_name> vkcube
``` BTW, the Ubuntu packages don't provide an ideal starting point for vulkan layer factory development. You may find it easier to work from the more generic linux SDK that is shipped as a tarball.

Answer (score -1):

Did you look at the documentation for using the VLF at https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.1.101.0/linux/layer_factory.html?

Comment: While the sentiment is appreciated, answers that are just a link to other answers don't tend to go over well on SO. You should put the salient content from that link into your answer.